# Why can't the index at which I want to replace a letter, be a variable in python?

Tags: python, list

So I have this assignment where I need to get a string from the user and then store that string as a list. The program will then ask the user for an index and a letter. The letter will then be replaced in their initial word at the given index.

This is how it should work:

- Enter a word: `cat`
- Enter an index: `1`
- Enter a letter: `o`
- Your new word is: `cot`

I can ask and store the users responses with functions correctly but I have a problem joining the list with this code:

```
word_list[index] = (letter)
word_string = "".join(word_list)
print (word_string)
```

`index` and `letter` are the variables that the user input

For some reason, the program only returns the letter variable that the user entered. How do I replace the letter they give at the index they give, then return the whole list as a string?

Entire Code:

```
### function that replaces letters
### at specificed indices
# function that asks user for an index
def get_index():
    while True:
        try:
            index = int(input("Enter an index (-1 to quit): "))
            if index == -1:
                quit
            elif index < -1:
                print ("Must be higher than -1!")
        except ValueError:
            print ("Enter a valid index!")
        return index
    # function that asks user for a letter
def get_letter():
    while True:
        try:
            letter = input("Enter a lowercase letter: ")
            if letter.isupper():
                print ("Must be a lower case letter")
        except ValueError:
            print ("Enter a valid letter!")
        return letter
# ask the user for a word
my_word = input("Enter a word: ")
# variable that holds current word as a list
my_word_list = list(my_word)
# call the function get_index() and store it as a variable called index1
index1 = get_index()
# call the function get_letter() and store it as a variable called letter1
letter1 = get_letter()
# print the word they entered as a list
print (my_word_list)
# insert their letter into the list at the index they gave
my_word_list[index1] = letter1
# turn the list into a string
my_word_string = "".join(my_word_list)
# print the final string
print (my_word_string)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Your code as written will throw an error.

Comment: if you use `input()` then it always returns string - even if you type number. you have to convert it into int()

Comment: The code you posted looks good so far. Give us the rest.

Comment: @furas that only works for python 3. In python 2, input() is interpreted as python code.

Comment: @JakobLovern I know it but I don't use Python 2 for the few years and I always expect that others also don't use it :)

Comment: @furas while 3.3 is the current version, module support for it is much weaker, so most people still use 2.7.

Comment: @JakobLovern I thought current version is 3.6 and most beginners like "the newest version" :)

Comment: Gah, oops. I've got 3.3 installed and it's never yelled at me to update. As for 'most beginners...' in my experience, it's a pretty much 50/50 split.

Comment: I updated the post with all of the code

Answer (score 3):

This should work (for Python 3)

```
word = input("enter a word")
letter = input("enter a letter")
index = input("enter an index")

# type conversion 
word_list = list(word) # as input always returns a string, and we can't modify a string
index = int(index)

# changing the list
word_list[index] = letter

# converting back the list to string
word = "".join(word_list)
print(word)
```

Comment: Yep - and since the second half is identical to OP's code the problem must be somewhere in the first half.

Comment: Thank you! It seems the problem was I wasn't converting the index into an integer.

Answer (score 1):

As Joe pointed out, strings are not mutable... but lists are. Although strings act like lists sometimes, they are not. If you explicitly make your word a list of characters, then you're example works.

```
word = input('word: ')
index = int(input('index: '))
letter  = input('letter: ')

word_list = list(word)
word_list[index] = letter
new_word = "".join(word_list)
print(new_word)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot replace characters directly is due to the `immutability` of `strings`. I.e. you cannot change them. So the way to replace a character at an index is to take a `slice` up to that `index` and then concatenate the `character` and then finally concatenate the rest of the `string`.

This method can be seen here:

```
word = "cat"
index = 1
replacement = "o"
new_word = word[:index] + replacement + word[index+1:]
#new_word --> 'cot'
```

Comment: um, `word_list[index] = letter; print(''.join(word_list))` *should also work*

Comment: OP does not get an exception, he has a wrong output.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga This is still a complete example that is the best way to do this and the OP can use...

Comment: @JoeIddon I disagree this is the best way to do this. Using a mutable data-structure then converting to a `str` at the end is the "usual" or idiomatic way in Python, bur regardless, this *doesn't answer the question* if we don't even know what is going wrong for the OP.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ok, I agree this does not answer the OP's question in that it doesn't answer "why isn't this code working?" but to answer that is pretty impossible without all the code!

Comment: @JoeIddon yep. The appropriate action, then, it to vote to put on hold to get the OP to clarify, especially given that this will almost certainly turn out to be a duplicate. I didn't downvote, btw...